# creating a list into a tree

Tags: scheme, racket

It doesn't work properly

```
(define (tree-insert v t)
  (cond((null? t)(make-tree v '() '()))
   ((eq? v (value t)) t)
   ((< v (value t)) (make-tree (value t)
                               (tree-insert v (left t))
                               (right t)))
   ((> v (value t)) (make-tree (value t)
                               (tree-insert v (right t))
                               (left t)))))
(define (insert-list l t)
  (if (null? l)
     t
     (insert-list (cdr l)
               (tree-insert(car l)t))))
(insert-list '(5 2 1 3 11 8 6 9 15 17) '())
; ==> (5 (2 (1 (17 () ()) (8 () ())) (3 (9 () ()) ())) (11 (15 () ()) (6 () ())))
```

Comment: `(eq? 5 5)` might be `#f` according to the report. You should use `=` or `eqv?` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are swapping left and right in the > case. try this instead:

```
(define (tree-insert v t)
  (cond((null? t)(make-tree v '()'()))
   ((eq? v (value t)) t)
   ((< v (value t)) (make-tree (value t)
                               (tree-insert v (left t))
                               (right t)))
   ((> v (value t)) (make-tree (value t)
                               (left t)
                               (tree-insert v (right t))))))
```